# How to suspend the subscription for a computed property?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way in KnockoutJS to suspend the subscription of a read/write computed observable? By that I mean that I don't want in particuar situations that it is affected by the changes of the other properties.

My concrete scenario is that I have properties:

- `.Total`
- `.Discount`
- `.FinalTotal`

The user can write new values in `Discount` and in `FinalTotal` inputs. If the user change `Discount`, the `FinalTotal` will be recalculated (it is the `Total` - the `Discount` calculated on it).

If the user changes `FinalTotal`, the `Discount` will be recalculated. So if I create them as computeds I would get this endless sequence of events:

1. User changes `Discount`
2. Knockout recalculates `FinalTotal`
3. Because `Discount` is dependent on `FinalTotal` this will recalculate `Discount`

...and so on.

Comment: I stumbled on this questin via Google because I want to suspend manual subscriptions to regular observables. However, this question sounds more like an issue with circular dependencies. In any case, the question lacks a short repro with actual code, which makes it hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your formulas are, but here is an example using two computed observables that works fine:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Total = ko.observable();
    self.Discount = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.Total() * .1;
    });
    self.FinalTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.Total() - self.Discount();
    });
}
```